# доступ к элементу словаря из другого файла

Tags: python, база-данных, list, словари, dict

Как получить доступ к элементу словаря из другого файла и сравнить их.
Пишу что-то типа хранилища данных.

[image: Первый файл]

[image: Второй файл]

Вот сам код:

```py
from tabulate import tabulate
import os
import cfg

while True:

    loggin = input('Enter Loggin:   ')
    if hasattr(cfg, loggin):
        
        while True:
            password = input('Enter Password:    ')
            
            if password == (cfg.loggin['pas']):
                
                print('All Ok\n')
                print(tabulate(cfg.EmailS, headers=cfg.EmailZ, tablefmt='pipe', stralign='center') + '\n')
                print('exit, editing, write to file (wtf)')
                
                while True:
                    mod = input('Enter mod:   ')
                    if mod == 'exit':
                        os.system('cls')
                        break
                    
                    elif mod == 'editing':
                        print('\n___EDITING MOD___')
                    
                    elif mod == 'wtf':
                        with open('table.txt', 'w') as f:
                            f.write(tabulate(cfg.EmailS, headers=cfg.EmailZ, tablefmt='pipe', stralign='center'))
                        print('\nComplate !')
                break    
            else:
                print('Invalid password !')




    elif loggin == 'clr':
        os.system('cls')
        
    elif loggin == 'exit':
        exit()
    
    else:
        print('User not found !\n')
```

И код второго файла:

```py
profel = {'pas' : '1234',
            'EmailZ' : ['Email', 'Password', 'data'],
            'EmailS' : ['profel@gmail.com', '1234', '14.07.2004']}

Mamy = {'pas' : '123',
        'EmailZ' : ['Email', 'Password', 'data'],
        'EmailS' : ['Mamy@gmail.com', '123', '19.04.2000']}
```

Comment: В файле на диске нет никаких списков. :-(

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/Почему-не-следует-выкладывать-код-данные-ошибки-в-виде-скриншотов

Comment: и еще, мне кажется что "wtf" не особо хорошее название для "write to file"

Comment: @FruitGames537 А для ника?

Comment: @WTFisGoingOn типо profel и Mamy